# Coding loops for text based game

Tags: python

I am working on Python with my students and want them to code a text-based game. I am also coding the game, being a fairly new coder. My problem is that when I use the def action1(run_leave): and then have if and elif and else statements, my code won't run. I suspect I need to use another set of codes, but can't sort out which. Once I see it, I can suss out how it works and what to do for other sets of code which are similar (action2, etc). I have put my code below. Any help is greatly appreciated. The first print commands work fine and I think set the mood very well - but once I get to run or leave I get errors.

EDIT: I have added the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    run
NameError: name 'run' is not defined

> > > 

Thanks in advance!

Bruce

```
print("""After a long and dangerous journey, you stand at your destination - the Pyramid of Osiris, the God of the Dead. It has been a long strange journey, almost as if
fate did not want you to arrive. But arrive you have!""")
print(" ")
print("""Now you stand in from of the Pyramid as a work crew led by Salim Al-Salaam
clears the last of the debris away from a magnificent set of sealed double
doors.You can feel the tension in the air as the last basket of rocks are
carried away from the entrance.""")
print(" ")
print("""As you gaze up at the steps and entrance, the briliance of the sun vanishes as
dark clouds cover it, and in the distance you see bright flashes of lightning,
followed by the rolling boom of thunder. A major storm is coming in.""")
print(" ")
print("""What do you choose to do?
Run for the entrance. (run)
Go back to your car and leave, because this is a sign you were never meant to
explore the pyramid. (leave)""")
print(" ")

def action1(run_leave):
    if run_leave == "run":
        print("""As you sprint up the stairs, you smell the ozone in the air getting
stronger. Suddenly, a lightning bolt flashes out of nowhere and strikes the stairs where you were just moments before, making your hair stand on end. Perhaps this wasn't such a good idea...""")

    elif run_leave == "leave":
        print("""In the car driving away, you look in the rear view mirror to see a strike of lightning hit the top of the Pyramid of Osiris, which begins to glow softly. As you turn around to watch the road ahead of you, a strange peace settles over your soul, and you realize you made the right choice.""")

    else:
        print("Your answer did not make sense. Leaving the game.")
```

Comment: How are you calling `action1`? What arguments are you passing to it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine in Python 3.5.0.

Please check if you are calling the function correctly. It should be called as action1('run') not action1(run)

```
After a long and dangerous journey, you stand at your destination - the Pyramid of Osiris, the God of the Dead. It has been a long strange journey, almost as if
fate did not want you to arrive. But arrive you have!

Now you stand in from of the Pyramid as a work crew led by Salim Al-Salaam
clears the last of the debris away from a magnificent set of sealed double
doors.You can feel the tension in the air as the last basket of rocks are
carried away from the entrance.

As you gaze up at the steps and entrance, the briliance of the sun vanishes as
dark clouds cover it, and in the distance you see bright flashes of lightning,
followed by the rolling boom of thunder. A major storm is coming in.

What do you choose to do?
Run for the entrance. (run)
Go back to your car and leave, because this is a sign you were never meant to
explore the pyramid. (leave)

>>> action1('run')
As you sprint up the stairs, you smell the ozone in the air getting
stronger. Suddenly, a lightning bolt flashes out of nowhere and strikes the stairs where you were just moments before, making your hair stand on end. Perhaps this wasn't such a good idea...
>>> action1('leave')
In the car driving away, you look in the rear view mirror to see a strike of lightning hit the top of the Pyramid of Osiris, which begins to glow softly. As you turn around to watch the road ahead of you, a strange peace settles over your soul, and you realize you made the right choice.
>>> action('shit')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    action('shit')
NameError: name 'action' is not defined
>>> action1('shit')
Your answer did not make sense. Leaving the game.
>>>
```

Comment: Post the text of the interactive shell instead of a screenshot of it.

Comment: Okay. Sorry. I am a newbie here.

Comment: Hi Priyankar. Thank you for responding. If you could post the code so I could see how it is formatted, that would be great. I am a visual type person, so seeing is half the battle :-) I am also looking at a site on making a text based game in python, but am worried that it might be too advanced for my students. However, it is fairly step by step.  Bruce

Comment: Hey Bruce. I haven't added any new code. I just checked the same code you posted in your question. Your code is working fine. When you run the code, it opens up in the interactive shell (whose text I have posted above). Since you haven't 'called' the function anywhere, you probably would have to call it manually in the interactive shell to check it as I have done here.

Comment: You could add code to get the input from the player and then call the function so that you wont have to do it after running the program. So you could add code like: text=input() and then call the function: action1(text)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted the indentation for you if blocks is wrong; you need all the `if`, `elif` and `else` to line up (this is because Python has meaningful whitespace, unlike other languages like javascript or C)

```
    if run_leave == "run":
        print("""As you sprint up the stairs, you smell the ozone in the air getting
stronger. Suddenly, a lightning bolt flashes out of nowhere and strikes the stairs where you were just moments before, making your hair stand on end. Perhaps this wasn't such a good idea...""")
    elif run_leave == "leave":
        print("""In the car driving away, you look in the rear view mirror to see a strike of lightning hit the top of the Pyramid of Osiris, which begins to glow softly. As you turn around to watch the road ahead of you, a strange peace settles over your soul, and you realize you made the right choice.""")

    else:
        print("Your answer did not make sense. Leaving the game.")
```

Comment: Thanks maxymoo. I double checked the indenting of my whitespace and it is fine. I still get this message:      >>> runTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    run
NameError: name 'run' is not defined